# Is there any equivalent of pgRouting for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pgrouting

I'm currently considering mongoDb for a geospatial project, in a near future the app should have a geospatial routing functionality.

But I can't find something like pgRouting equivalent for mongoDb

Is there any solution to calculate a route with mongoDb ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer for pgRouting and I have played with mongoDB spatial stuff, but I'm not aware of any routing add-ons for mongoDB. In fact the geospatial part of mongoDB was very limited when compared to postGIS.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use postGiS for this project.